# The pexpect pxssh do not create my requirement directory

Tags: python, pexpect, pxssh

I use the `pexpect` module to login a ssh server and then mkdir a directory:

```
from pexpect import pxssh

s = pxssh.pxssh()

s.login(server='43.24.24.29', username='root', password='my_password')

s.send('mkdir aaa')

s.logout()
```

it works, but I find, in the server, there created `aaaexit` directory, there is not `aaa` directory:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls
aaaexit  anaconda-ks.cfg
```

I know there maybe the `s.logout()` affected it, but how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
s.send('mkdir aaa\n')
```

to avoid the issue.